# My table of figures prints weird spacing

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, koma-script

My table of figures somehow prints weird spacing between some entries, and I can't figure out this behaviour.

[image]

It is produced as follows:

```
 \cleardoublepage
 \phantomsection
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
 \listoffigures
```

These are the packages I am using:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside,toc=chapterentrywithdots, openany]{scrbook}
% INCLUDES
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % Zitierstil [Zahl]
%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex} % Zitierstil Autor(Jahr) im Text
\usepackage[
%showframe,% Seitenlayout anzeigen
left=3cm,
right=2.5cm,
top=2.5cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
%includeheadfoot
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[list=true, font=large, labelfont=bf, 
labelformat=brace, position=top]{subcaption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}%conflicts with subfigure, needet for table of equations
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{etoc}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% damit \chapter Seiten ebenso die Seitenzahl rechts Anzeigen.
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
% um "andere" Seitenzahlen zu löschen
\cfoot[]{}
\

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}% Acronyme in Fußzeile 
%\usepackage[footnote,printonlyused]{acronym}% Acronyme in Fußzeile , nur beim ersten vorkommen im text
\usepackage[]{acronym}% Acronyme aussschrieben und danach in klammern abkürzung anfügen.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%TODO PAKET AKTIVIEREN/DEAKTIVIEREN
%\usepackage[german,colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption]{todonotes}% Todo Paket Aktiv
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}%Todo Paket deaktivieren für Finale version
```

Comment: unrelated but loading both mathptmx and lmodern at the same time is rather strange (if you do want a times roman clone there are better clones these days than mathptmx, newtxmath for example, but if you want latin modern fonts then you do not want mathptmx at all

Comment: Add class option `listof=nochaptergap`.

Comment: Do not use package `tocloft` with a KOMA-Script class. A list of equations can be created using the KOMA-Script commands. Load `hyperref` after the other packages.

Comment: Hello guys, im a newb, this is my first paper ever with Latex so I used the template provided by my university, which loaded these packages, I haven't changed a lot. Where would I add the class option?

Comment: Yup, added in the documentclass and that fixed it. Dude, you helped me tons, thank you a lot!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, KOMA-Script provides an option to remove the default gap between figures of different chapters.

Comment: @Kevin Do not use this template. See [Minimale Vorlage vs. maximale Probleme](https://komascript.de/latexvorlage) (German).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default figures and tables are grouped by chapters in LOF and LOT. The standard classes `book` and `report` do the same.

The KOMA-Script classes provide option `listof=nochaptergap` to remove these gapes between figure or table entries of different chapters.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[listof=nochaptergap,listof=totoc]{scrbook}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Third figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Additional remarks:**

Do not load package `tocloft` with a KOMA-Script class. These classes load and use package KOMA-Script package `tocbasic` automatically. Therefore it is possible to create additional lists without an additional package.

Do not add the LOF to the TOC manually. You can use class option `listof=totoc` instead. But package `tocloft` breaks this feature, so do not use this package with a KOMA-Script class. `tocloft` also breaks the option `toc=chapterentrywithdots` in your MWE.

Do not load packages more than once. Packages `chngcntr` and `inputenc` are not needed with an uptodate TeX distribution. Package `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, which loads `graphicx` and `xcolor`.

Load `hyperref` after the other packages.

See also the comment of @DavidCarlisle below your question regarding the fonts.